# Is it possible ( and a good idea ) to use app.config as kind of project file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a small project which needs some settings to be configured at runtime. Because the app.settings creation allows to simply create all configurable items I need for loading automatically at startup, I would like to use this. However, is it possible to use the appconfig mechanism for storing simple project informations, which can be loaded on demand ? What I would need then is a simple way of Load/Save the .settings file in the prebuilt Settings structure of my project. Is this possible and if yes, a good idea ?

Comment: do accept ans if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it good idea to put data in app.config by creating custom section

here is tutorial for you for doing this

[How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

[App.Config and Custom Configuration Sections](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/11/13/app-config-and-custom-configuration-sections.aspx)

Comment: I would even add: That's exactly what app.settings is made for!

Comment: hmm, well, but it looks quite complicated and not straight forward. At which point I would say kind of Settings.Load("\path\to\special.config") or Settings.Save("\path\to\special.config"). That looks a bit unclear to me...